# How to see what specific error is occurring during write function

Tags: swift, error-handling, stream, inputstream, outputstream

If this question has been asked before, please let me know and I will remove this question. However, I was not able to find one answering this.

I'm currently using this function: 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/outputstream/1410720-write

```
func write(_ buffer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, maxLength len: Int) -> Int
```

to write to a stream. It returns an integer, and according to the documentation this integer is used to determine if the data was sent successfully or not:

- A positive number indicates the number of bytes written.
- 0 indicates that a fixed-length stream and has reached its capacity.
- -1 means that the operation failed; more information about the error can be obtained with streamError.

I'm curious about the last one. In my code I'm getting the value of this error, which is -1 in my case. I'm hoping to see what specifically is failing. But how do I get an error object from an integer?

So basically, how do I get this: "more information about the error can be obtained with streamError."

Thanks.

EDIT:

First off thanks for the answer already. However, I ended up using the following code:

```
    for buffer in buffers {
        let output = outputStream?.write((buffer.mData?.load(as: UnsafePointer<UInt8>.self))!, maxLength: Int(buffer.mDataByteSize))

        if output == -1 {
            let error = outputStream?.streamError
            print("\(#file) > \(#function) > Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

And it's printing out that the error is nil.

Comment: What kind of stream is `outputStream`? Did you `open()` the stream before writing to it?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I forgot to open the stream. Have you ever seen the error "The operation couldn’t be completed. Bad address."?

Comment: Apparently `streamError` is not set if the stream has not been opened. – You would get "bad address" if the buffer does not contain a valid address. Example: `let written = stream.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bitPattern: 1)!, maxLength: 4)`

Comment: @MartinR Okay, so this means that the actual "UnsafePointer<UInt8>" object has a bad address?

Comment: "Bad address" is the Unix error EFAULT and means that the *"data to be written to the file points outside the process's allocated address space"*. You'll see the possible Unix errors with "man 2 write" in the Terminal  window.

Comment: That's very strange... Do you mind if I show you what I have, I don't see how it could be outside the allocated address space. @MartinR

Comment: I would suggest to post a new question, preferably with a reproducible test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `InputStream` and `OutputStream` inherit from `Stream`, which has
a [`streamError`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/stream/1416359-streamerror) property:

> Returns an NSError object representing the stream error.

Simple example:

```
let written = stream.write(buffer, maxLength: length)
if written == -1 {
    if let error = stream.streamError {
    print(stream.streamError?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
}
```

Apparently there are cases where `streamError` is not set after a failed
write, e.g. if you did not `open()` the stream.